# pandas dataframe from nested dictionary with uneven depth

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary of the following form:

```
{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z':{'a': 3, 'b': 4}, 'w': {'a': 5, 'b': 6}}
```

I want to create a df like this:

[image]

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you have a third level?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74471768/how-to-convert-nested-dictionary-to-levelled-pandas-dataframe/74475370?noredirect=1#comment131469530_74475370

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only 2 levels:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z':{'a': 3, 'b': 4}, 'w': {'a': 5, 'b': 6}}

data = {}
for k1, v1 in d.items():
    if isinstance(v1, dict):
        for k2, v2 in v1.items():
            data[(k1, k2)] = v2
    else:
        data[(k1, '')] = v1

df = pd.DataFrame([data.values()], columns=data)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   x  y  z     w      # index, level 1
         a  b  a  b   # index, level 2
0  1  2  3  4  5  6   # values
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! For now, I have 2 levels, but in the future, I might have a third level. If you have a more general solution, that would be awesome!